# Rewriting a statement using LINQ(C#)

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to write the folowing using lambda(C#)

```
private static void GetRecordList(List<CustomerInfo> lstCustinfo)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)

            lstCustinfo.Add(new CustomerInfo { CountryCode = "USA", CustomerAddress = "US Address" + i.ToString(), CustomerName = "US Customer Name" + i.ToString(), ForeignAmount = i * 50 });

        else
           lstCustinfo.Add(new CustomerInfo { CountryCode = "UK", CustomerAddress = "UK Address" + i.ToString(), CustomerName = "UK Customer Name" + i.ToString(), ForeignAmount = i * 80 });

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd want to rewrite this as a lambda. To make it harder to understand?

Comment: Maybe to save the money for an Obfuscator tool... ;)

Comment: no.. I am very new to lambda and linq.. I am trying to use this new features.. so whatevr I write using foreach, I try to do the same in linq or lambda.. Basically I want to learn it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<CustomerInfo> lstCustinfo = 
    Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => (i % 2 == 0)
        ? new CustomerInfo { CountryCode = "USA", CustomerAddress = "US Address" + i.ToString(), CustomerName = "US Customer Name" + i.ToString(), ForeignAmount = i * 50 }
        : new CustomerInfo { CountryCode = "UK", CustomerAddress = "UK Address" + i.ToString(), CustomerName = "UK Customer Name" + i.ToString(), ForeignAmount = i * 80 })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This obviously works and answers the question, but it seems *a lot* more readable in the original version!

Comment: Now, the question is: Is this lambda expression really better? When counting lines to write for the developer: yes. When considering the readability for other developers which might have to modify the code later on: absolutely NO! That's why I do not use lambda expressions very often.

Comment: great and thnks for the help.. also I learned something new. thanks again

Comment: Nitpicking but: `lstCustinfo` is already defined as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You must first define the selection, then add it to the incoming list:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
var customers = from i in range
                select (i % 2 == 0) ?
                      new CustomerInfo 
                      { 
                                    CountryCode = "USA", 
                                    CustomerAddress = "US Address" + i, 
                                    CustomerName = "US Customer Name" + i, 
                                    ForeignAmount = i * 50 
                      }
                      :
                      new CustomerInfo 
                      { 
                                    CountryCode = "UK", 
                                    CustomerAddress = "UK Address" + i,
                                    CustomerName = "UK Customer Name" + i,
                                    ForeignAmount = i * 80 
                      };

lstCustinfo.AddRange(customers);
```

Or perhaps even more explicit:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
var usCustomers = from i in range
                  where i % 2 == 0 
                select new CustomerInfo 
                      { 
                                    CountryCode = "USA", 
                                    CustomerAddress = "US Address" + i, 
                                    CustomerName = "US Customer Name" + i, 
                                    ForeignAmount = i * 50 
                      };

var ukCustomers = from i in range
                where i % 2 != 0
                select new CustomerInfo 
                      { 
                                    CountryCode = "UK", 
                                    CustomerAddress = "UK Address" + i,
                                    CustomerName = "UK Customer Name" + i,
                                    ForeignAmount = i * 80 
                      };

lstCustinfo.AddRange(usCustomers.Union(ukCustomers));
```